# Populating string with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line of code inside me JS:

```
'<a class="txt333 clps" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" '+
     'href="#collapse_reqConf'+sent+'" '+
     'aria-controls="collapse'+sent+'" '+
     'data-parent="#accordion_reqConf'+sent+'">'
```

Which populates var sent and produces the following results (from source view):

```
<a class="txt333 clps" data-parent="#accordion_reqConf137" aria-controls="collapse137" href="#collapse_reqConf'+sent+'" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse">
```

I cannot figure out why the one within **href** attribute is not being inserted properly...

---

UPDATE: WORKING ANSWER IN MY LAST COMMENT.

Comment: That string is properly formatted. [There must be something else going on.](https://jsfiddle.net/4ooh2soa/)

Comment: seems to be okay : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/uwsutrz7/2/

Comment: Work fine for me too.

Comment: What can possibly be? I insert different values throughout and as you can see even in this string it work fine 2/3...

Comment: @santa Maybe clear your cache?!... And how do you insert it?

Comment: This is ridiculous... I have renamed the var (just in case), added a console.log output. Everything populates OK, except this blessed href... I output it via loop, after my server returns response to my ajax post. Weird.

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you post more of the code, like the ajax handler and the the loop that is outputting the tag? The fact that the order of the attributes is different tells me what you posted might not be the exact code.

Comment: How are you seeing this in the source view? The Source panel just shows the original HTML, not the result of DOM changes from Javascript.

Comment: The updated code works for me as well. Where are you viewing the source -- browser inspector? Which browser? Is this happening to every row in the loop? Without being able to replicate, I would try random stuff like using one of the other vars in the href, omitting the '#', or putting the href as the last attribute.

Comment: Tried replacing with different vars, put at the beginning, end, alas same effect. Finally moved href attr into it's own var and appended at the end, similarly as in accepted answer, and voila -- worked. Still don't know what causes it, but I wasted enough time and must move on. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery anyways, you try something like the following to create DOM elements using jQuery.  Personally, I feel that creating elements using strings of HTML is error-prone, makes the code hard to read and debug.  I create the `<a></a>` element that you are having an issue with using jQuery and append its containing elements using elements created from string.

```
var inner =  '<div class="row">'+
                 '<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8">'+
                     '<table class="w100p text-success b">'+
                         '<tr>'+
                             '<td width="50%" class="nowrap pad10rt">'+ '<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg valignMid xtraSm"></i> 4:00 pm'+'</td>'+
                             '<td width="50%"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg valignMid xtraSm"></i> x '+part+'</td>'+
                         '</tr>'+
                     '</table>'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 text-right">'+
                     '<i class="indicator fa fa-fw fa-chevron-right"></i>'+
                 '</div>'+
             '</div>';


var attribs = {
  "class": "txt333 clps",
  "data-toggle": "collapse",
  "aria-expanded": false,
  "href": "#collapse_reqConf" + sent,
  "aria-controls": "collapse" + sent,
  "data-parent": "#accordion_reqConf" + sent
};


var elStr = $('<a>').attr(attribs).append($(inner)).prop('outerHTML');
console.log(elStr);
```